# How to get a list of all files that have changed in SCons?

Tags: python, build, compilation, scons

While trying to get my build to use single compilation units I have found it necessary to test whether, given a certain filename, the respective file has changed since the last build, and then based on whether it has or not, to treat it differently (add it to a particular scu or not).

I have tried constructing a file object, and calling Node.changed() on it, but this always returns False, even when the file has changed.

How can I test to file to see if SCons thinks it has changed?

Comment: Your approach will probably not work because you're not checking changed() in the build phase, but while reading all the SConscripts. Can you give some more information about why you have to sometimes include files and sometimes not (minimal example) in your SCUs? Shouldn't the list of "#include"s within a single SCU stay constant over time?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `AddPostAction` command ?

http://www.scons.org/doc/2.1.0/HTML/scons-user/a10706.html

It basically execute an action after a target have been built.

Comment: The thing is, I need to construct the SCUs before I can build them, and I can only build them if I know what files have been changed.

Using this method, I would have to build twice, once to figure out what has changed and construct the SCU, then actually build the SCU